# Django URLs: changing the default "/questions/" in OSQA URLs to something else

Tags: python, django, osqa

I am trying to mod [OSQA](https://github.com/OSQA/osqa) to not use `/questions` *anywhere* in URLs, and change it to some other string, say `/thisinstead`.

### Some examples

When the user clicks on the questions tab, instead of linking to `mydomain.com/questions/`, it should link to `mydomain.com/somethingelse/`.

Likewise, instead of `mydomain.com/questions/3/Q3Title/`, it should link to `mydomain.com/somethingelse/3/Q3Title/`.

And so forth.

What would be the most elegant approach to accomplishing this?

Comment: have you checked the `urls.py`?  I have never seen osqa source but i think if they use `reverse` it could be as trivial as changing the `urls.py` entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a very quick glance at the OSQA source code, and all of their urls are translated. So, you can just modify https://github.com/OSQA/osqa/blob/master/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po line 398, run `django-admin compilemessages` and done.

For more info on customization, look at section D in https://github.com/OSQA/osqa/blob/master/INSTALL